# Necessity to redeclare functions after jQuery's load

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with jQuery's `load()`. This is my code:

```
    $('nav#pagination ul li a').live('click', function() {

        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').parent('nav').fadeOut('fast',function() {
            $(this).load(url + ' nav#pagination > *', function() {
                $(this).fadeIn();
            })
        })

        return false;
    })
```

HTML:

```
<div class="block" id="onShelf">
        <header class="prefix_1">
            <h2>Na półce</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="inner prefix_1 suffix_1">
            ## normal text ##
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <nav id="pagination" class="clearfix">
                <ul>
                <li><b>1</b></li>
                <li><a href="/page/8"5px;">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/16"5px;">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/24"5px;">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/32"5px;">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/40"5px;">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/8"5px;">→</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click on one of those links, it works, but only once. It doesn't work any more and doesn't load any scripts in loaded content. I have to redeclare each function inside, after loading. What can I do to ommit this, well, unelegant solution?

I tried `live`, `click`, `delegate` and `bind`.

Comment: Is `}` at the end of code, a closing bracket for a function? Do you see any error on the console? Please note that `live` method is deprecated.

Comment: Can you create jsFiddle or similar? It would help us  :) .. or simple post some HTML for faster testing...

Comment: Sorry about that bracket at the end, I copied too much :) And, since JSFiddle doesn't seem to work (at least for me), I posted my HTML in my question.

Comment: @undefined I used `live` here, but I tried `on` which is newer and it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like

```
$(body).on('click', 'nav#pagination ul li a', function () {
    your code here
});
```

You can use any non-refreshable element instead of body